# Restoring dotnet tools found in csproj file. What does this mean for my project?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio-mac

The csproj file of my newly created Android project in VS for Mac 2022 looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0-android</TargetFramework>
<SupportedOSPlatformVersion>31</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
<ApplicationId>com.companyname.TestProjectAndroid</ApplicationId>
<ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>
<ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Content.Builder.Task" Version="3.8.1.303" />
<PackageReference Include="MonoGame.Framework.Android" Version="3.8.1.303" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<None Remove="proguard.cfg" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<ProguardConfiguration Include="proguard.cfg" />
</ItemGroup>
<Target Name="RestoreDotnetTools" BeforeTargets="Restore">
<Message Text="Restoring dotnet tools" Importance="High" />
<Exec Command="dotnet tool restore" />
</Target>
</Project>
```

At the end it has Restoring dotnet tools and Importance="High". What does this Restoring dotnet tools mean? Is something wrong with my project?

I use VS for Mac 2022 17.3.8 (build 5).

Comment: Restore is going to make sure the code runs with latest version of net and if newer version than net 6.0 exists ask if you want to update.

Comment: OK. I thought that there is a problem with my project and that I need to do something because "Restoring dotnet tools" is written in the csproj file.

Comment: Try testing by changing the target in the csproj to an older version of Net and see what happends.

Comment: I changed the target from net6.0-android to net5.0-android. Then VS displays a message that .NET 5.0 is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future. But the project is not updated automatically. VS does nothing to solve it. I need to do it manually in the csproj file.